# Finding eigenvalues of a matrix after finding its rank and nullity

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose i have a nxn matrix with all entries as 1, after Row reducing, I have found the rank and nullity of the matrix. What should i do next to find the eigenvalues without using determinants? Is eigenspace and nullspace related in some way?

Comment: If all entries of the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ are 1, you can just explicitly solve the equation $Ax = \lambda x$.

Comment: The null space is nontrivial, so you know that zero is an eigenvalue. And note that the vector with all entries equal to 1 is an eigenvector. What is the corresponding eigenvalue?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be your original matrix: I assume that you want to know its eigenvalues.

You have row reduced this to $J$ the all 1-s matrix; this has rank 1.

Hence $A$ has rank 1; and hence $A$ has nullity $n-1$.

As the nullity is $n-1$ we have a subspace of dimension $n-1$ on which $A$ acts as $0$; that is a subspace of dimension $n-1$ of $0$-eigenvectors. So $(n-1)$ of the eigenvalues equal $0$.

As for the other eigenvalue, we can use the fact that the sum of the eigenvalues is the sum of the diagonal entries of $A$; so it is $\text{tr}(A)$.